# How to restructure Mongodb Linq query to work in Cosmos Db?

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a collection that stores several different types that all inherit from BaseEntity, among those the type LoginUser. The following code in MyQuery

```
public IMongoQueryable<LoginUser> LoginUserQuery
{
    get
    {
        return _database.GetCollection<BaseEntity>(collectionName).AsQueryable<BaseEntity>().OfType<LoginUser>();
    }
}

void MyQuery()
{
    var user = LoginUserQuery.Where(item => item.SomeProperty == "myemail@example.com").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
}
```

gives error

> $match is currently only supported when it is the first and only stage of the aggregation pipeline. Please restructure your query to combine multiple $match stages into a single $match stage.

The query as seen in the exception is

> {{ "aggregate" : "eMeetings", "pipeline" : [{ "$match" : { "_t" : "LoginUser" } }, { "$match" : { "NormalizedEmail" : "myemail@example.com" } }], "cursor" : { } }}

Can I fix this somehow? Or will it be fixed by this recently closed issue? https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-azure-cosmos-db/suggestions/34115251-add-support-for-match-in-aggregation-pipeline-no

Comment: Can you please enable or ensure you have enabled the aggregation pipeline preview feature in the Azure Portal: Azure: #CosmosDB extends support for MongoDB aggregation pipeline, unique indexes, and more - https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-cosmosdb-extends-support-for-mongodb-aggregation-pipeline-unique-indexes-and-more/

Comment: @MikeUbezziMSFT I’m using the emulator at the moment. Is it available there also?

Comment: Emulator should have the same experience as Azure Cosmos DB MongoDB API but I do not see a new version of the Emulator available for download at this time. Can you please send a well crafted note with these details, along with asking when the latest version of the Emulator will be available, to askcosmosdb@microsoft.com. Thank you!